# Relation between complex-valued analytic functions and (anti-)holomorphic functions

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, complex-geometry

Suppose that $M$ is a complex manifold. Denote by $\mathcal{O}_M$ resp. $\overline{\mathcal{O}_M}$ the sheaf of holomorphic functions resp. anti-holomorphic functions on $M$ and by $\mathcal{O}_M^{\mathbb{R}}$ the sheaf of real analytic functions. Then the sheaf $\mathcal{O}_M^{\mathbb{R}}\otimes \mathbb{C}$ contains $\mathcal{O}_M$ and $\overline{\mathcal{O}_M}$.

I am wondering wheter one can reconstruct $\mathcal{O}_M^{\mathbb{R}}\otimes \mathbb{C}$ from $\mathcal{O}_M$ and $\overline{\mathcal{O}_M}$.

Intuitively, I would expect $\mathcal{O}_M^{\mathbb{R}}\otimes \mathbb{C}\cong \mathcal{O}_M \otimes_{\mathbb{C}} \overline{\mathcal{O}_M}$. Is something like this possible or am I missing something?

Further, the sheaf $\mathcal{O}_M^{\mathbb{R}}\otimes \mathbb{C}$ comes naturally with a conjugation that allows to pick out the sheaf $\mathcal{O}_M^{\mathbb{R}}$. The only choice I see on $\mathcal{O}_M \otimes_{\mathbb{C}} \overline{\mathcal{O}_M}$ would be $s\otimes \bar{t} \mapsto t\otimes \bar{s}$, which seems strange, because fixed points in basic elements would be $s\otimes \bar{s}$, i.e. squares of absolute values of holomorphic functions.

**EDIT:** I have recently learned about the topological tensor product of locally convex vector spaces. So, for smooth functions $C^{\infty}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)\otimes C^{\infty}\left(\mathbb{R}\right)$, with the usual tensor product of vector spaces, is only a subspace of $C^{\infty}\left(\mathbb{R}^2\right)$ and one needs to employ the  topological tensor product to obtain all of $C^{\infty}\left(\mathbb{R}^2\right)$ (see e.g. [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_tensor_product#cite_note-1)). I was wondering if the same exact thing is happening here. Has someone seen a discussion in this direction?

Comment: You need to replace $\otimes$ by a closure version of it to get the real analytic functions from the holomorphic and anti-holomorphic ones (on small enough open sets)

Comment: @reuns Can you expand on your comment? Closure is usually defined in reference to something, e.g. a topology, a norm,... I suspect that you are hinting at the possible fact that not every analytic function can be written as a finite sum of products of holomorphic and anti-holomorphic functions. Do you have a specific reference or theorem/proposition in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tensor product needed here is the so called "analytic tensor product". It is e.g. discussed in "Analytische Stellenalgebren" by Grauert & Remmert.

The idea is that $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{K}^n}\hat{\otimes}\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{K}^k}$ is assumed to be $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{K}^{n+k}}$ and its shown that this behaves as a tensor product should. Then if $\mathcal{O}_{M}$ and $\mathcal{O}_{N}$ are quotients by the ideals $I_M$ and $I_N$. Then $\mathcal{O}_{M}\hat{\otimes}\mathcal{O}_{N}$ is the quotient of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{K}^{n+k}}$ by the ideal generated by $I_M\otimes 1 + 1\otimes I_N$.

This works for $\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R},\mathbb{C}$.